# Tag proposal: "Law enforcment" as synonym for police

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

Well, title says everything.

---

When I came here first I tried to find some information about interacting with law enforcing institutes (basically [police](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/police)), but didn't found any tag for it (by trying different tags in the bar below the question). Only when I looked at all tags I saw the police-tag.

---

I'm by no means an expert on law. If [law-enforcement](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/law-enforcement) is fundamentally different from [police](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/police) I want to apologize in advance.

Answer (score 2):

There are law enforcement agencies that aren't police. As an easy example, consider the Federal Bureau of Investigation. They enforce the law, but aren't commonly called police.

Comment: Would it then be a good idea to add it as extra-tag and link both to each other?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by an extra tag, or by linking them to each other. And I don't think it's a good idea to make a tag for every law enforcement agency not a called police in the world. If and when the need arises for the [tag:law-enforcement] tag, users with sufficient reputation may create and use it.